# How to use a loop in a listview pager adapter

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin

Please I am new to android development using Xamarin android, I followed one tutorial (https://gist.github.com/AlejandroRuiz/c1338bb0166754c6da3d) on how to create a viewpager and i did everything right and it's working well. Here is the code for the page adapter

public class CardsPagerAdapter : Android.Support.V13.App.FragmentStatePagerAdapter
    {
        public class EventPage
        {
            // Image ID for this tree image:
            public string date;

```
        // Caption text for this image:
        public string myEvent;

        // Returns the ID of the image:
        public string Date { get { return date; } }


        // Returns the caption text for the image:
        public string Events { get { return myEvent; } }
    }



    static EventPage[] mCards = {
        new EventPage {date = "12 October",
                       myEvent = "1938 - Production began on \"The Wizard of Oz.\""},
        new EventPage { date = "13 October",
                       myEvent = "1893 The melody for Happy Birthday To You was copyright registered. Happy Birthday was originally published as Good Morning To All in a book called Song Stories for the Kindergarten written by Mildred and Patty Hill." },
        new EventPage { date = "14 October",
                       myEvent = "1835 Henry Blair received a patent in for an improved corn planter." },
        new EventPage { date = "15 October",
                       myEvent = "1991 Pizza Hut was trademark registered." },
        new EventPage { date = "16 October",
                       myEvent = "1900 Frank Sprague was granted a patent for a multi-control for electric trains." },
        new EventPage { date = "17 October",
                       myEvent = "1961 \"HOT ROCKS\" Candy was trademark registered." },
        new EventPage { date = "18 October",
                       myEvent = "1958 - The first computer-arranged marriage took place on Art Linkletter's show." },
        new EventPage { date = "19 October",
                       myEvent = "1986 - Foremost journalist, Dele Giwa, assassinated by a parcel bomb which is often blamed on the Babangida regime" },
    };

    private List<Fragment> mCardsFragments { get; set; }


    public CardsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) : base(fm)
    {

           mCardsFragments = new List<Fragment>{

            new PagerFragment(mCards[0].date, mCards[0].myEvent),
            new PagerFragment(mCards[1].date, mCards[1].myEvent),
            new PagerFragment(mCards[2].date, mCards[2].myEvent),
            new PagerFragment(mCards[3].date, mCards[3].myEvent),
            new PagerFragment(mCards[4].date, mCards[4].myEvent),
            new PagerFragment(mCards[5].date, mCards[5].myEvent),
            new PagerFragment(mCards[6].date, mCards[6].myEvent),
            new PagerFragment(mCards[7].date, mCards[7].myEvent),

        };
    }

    #region implemented abstract members of PagerAdapter

    public override int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return mCardsFragments.Count;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region implemented abstract members of FragmentStatePagerAdapter

    public override Fragment GetItem(int position)
    {
        return mCardsFragments[position];
    }

    public override Java.Lang.ICharSequence GetPageTitleFormatted(int position)
    {
        return new Java.Lang.String(mCards[position].date);
    }


    #endregion
}
```

The issue i am facing now is how to dynamically enter value into the PagerFragment using a loop because i am getting my data from a database.

Code where I need the loop to be

mCardsFragments = new List{

//Want the loop to be inside here

```
            new PagerFragment(mCards[0].date, mCards[0].myEvent),
            new PagerFragment(mCards[1].date, mCards[1].myEvent),
            new PagerFragment(mCards[2].date, mCards[2].myEvent),
            new PagerFragment(mCards[3].date, mCards[3].myEvent),
            new PagerFragment(mCards[4].date, mCards[4].myEvent),
            new PagerFragment(mCards[5].date, mCards[5].myEvent),
            new PagerFragment(mCards[6].date, mCards[6].myEvent),
            new PagerFragment(mCards[7].date, mCards[7].myEvent),
```

};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mCardsFragments = new List<Fragment>();
for (int i = 0; i < mCards.Count; i++)
{
    mCardsFragments.Add(new PagerFragment(mCards[i].date, mCards[i].myEvent)); 
}
```

Comment: pls i am unable to get the Title of the viewpager, please can you help me

The Title Code:

public override Java.Lang.ICharSequence GetPageTitleFormatted(int position)
        {
            return new Java.Lang.String(mCards[position].date);
        }

Here is the code for the viewpager and its working

mCardsFragments = new List<Fragment>();

            foreach (var events in table)
            {
                mCardsFragments.Add(new PagerFragment(events.EventDate, events.Content));

            }
Pls help me...